# How to run exe file in Ubuntu

Tags: windows, matlab, executable

Is it possible to run a .exe file in Ubuntu in a script?
For example a simple Matlab code like this:

```
system("dir/WAV2RAW.exe")
```

Comment: If the .exe file is a windows executeable, you can't run it directly in Ubuntu (or other Linux's). Either you should install Wine and run it through that, or find a utility in Ubuntu that does the same as the windows one.

Comment: Could be a slight case of the XY-problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... If you want to convert a wav-file to raw PCM data for processing in Matlab, you could use a linux-tool like sox instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383576/how-to-convert-16bit-wav-to-raw-audio

Comment: Is WAV2RAW.exe the only EXE program you want to run, or do you have several other DOS / Windows / .NET programs?

Comment: I'm relatively sure that Matlab (and its open-source clone Octave) have native functions to parse WAVE headers and data as well as to write raw PCM data since I used them in the past. Those would obviate the need for an external conversion application unless the PCM data doesn't fit into main memory.

Answer (score 35):

I think you should use Wine.

```
sudo apt-get install wine
wine dir/WAV2RAW.exe
```

Or Mono if you know that exe is .NET application:

```
sudo apt install mono-runtime
mono dir/WAV2RAW.exe
```

Comment: You don't need to `chmod`. Besides that, it's worth noting that not all software runs under wine. YMMV.

Comment: You seem to have [added the `chmod` line](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/999295/2) according to my comment. However, I think it is only necessary if you want to run the `.exe` file directly, i.e. without prepending `wine` to the command line – like OP wants to. I haven’t tested it with Wine but it behaves this way with .NET exe files (`mono my.exe` or `chmod +x my.exe && ./my.exe`) or even shell scripts (`sh script.sh` or `chmod +x script.sh && ./script.sh`).

Comment: @Melebius that works because Wine [registers itself in binfmts](https://askubuntu.com/a/776010/113421) when installed from the official Ubuntu package.

Comment: Recent Ubuntu editions seem to want `sudo apt-get install wine-stable`

Comment: No, wine-stable [is 3.0.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=wine-stable&searchon=names), so old; while wine is synonym of wine-development thus [5.0.3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=wine) is newer.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

You could use 'sox' to convert from raw to wav file types:

```
sudo apt install sox
```

will install the program, then

```
sox --type raw <infile> --type wav <outfile>
```

would perform a simple conversion from the raw to wav formats