# Wine + PlayOnLinux + SelfExtractingArchive.exe

Tags: playonlinux, executable

What if I want to install Windows software using PlayOnLinux, but the only .exe file I can select is a self-extracting archive?  How do I extract the actual main program file that PlayOnLinux is asking for?

Comment: Doesn't matter what program; it only matters that I can't point PlayOnLinux to any program file until it's been extracted.  And I don't know how to run an .exe file under Ubuntu (without Wine) in order to unzip the archive.

Comment: The .exe self-extracting archive may have an .msi file inside. If so you can run it like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/671277/is-it-possible-to-run-a-windows-msi-installer/671280#671280, but I don't know how to extract files from the .exe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run exe file in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999294/how-to-run-exe-file-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @N0rbert I don't think this question is an exact duplicate because this question is not about an ordinary .exe file. It is about a self-extracting archive .exe file. There are special Windows programs to extract the contents from such files and with hacking maybe p7zip-full from the default Ubuntu repos could be harnessed to do it in Linux (but I have not done this and I do not have the example .exe self-extracting archive to test if it could be done.)

Comment: @karel. Thanks! I retracted close vote. I support your p7zip-full solution. I was very surprised when Engrampa (fork of file-roller) openned exe-file archive and showed its contents ... I tested with `file` (first was *PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows, Nullsoft Installer self-extracting archive*, second - *PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows*).

Comment: That could be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested two exe-files with File Roller and Engrampa (fork of `file-roller`). They were extracted normally. All we need is to have `p7zip-full` package installed (as [@karel already noted](https://askubuntu.com/a/1077681/66509)).

The `file` utility reports that they have two file-types:

- *PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows, Nullsoft Installer self-extracting archive*
- *PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows* (for example 7-Zip and WinRAR from Windows create such files when SFX ZIP or SFX RAR was chosen).

**Note:** the SFX RAR archive could not be opened with this method on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. You can use [Wine for this purpose](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999294/how-to-run-exe-file-in-ubuntu) here.