# at nautilus, javascript file opens with "windows based script host", what is that?

Tags: javascript, autorun

what that "windows" thing is doing here?
how safe is it?

when I double click on the js file (expecting gedit), it starts some process that I cannot find with `ps`... so,
what executable is that thing?

how/when that was installed? it is here from the beggining?

Any real use to have it installed? if not, I will uninstall it..

Comment: Do you have wine installed?

Comment: @muru yep! oh... well, I dont want that thing anyway, unless it is useful?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/323437/158442 and the question linked to that post

Answer (score 1):

Windows Based Scripting Host (WSH) is a API to run Active Scripting languages like JScript or VBScript.

If the .js file you're trying to open is from a Windows system originally, it might actually be a JScript file (MS's dialect of JavaScript, or if new enough, a "JScript .NET" file) instead of a regular JavaScript file and have calls to ActiveX, etc.

You might want to take a look at / edit it in the Terminal (with nano for example) first, instead of trying to open it with gedit - just to see what it really contains.

Without knowing more about your system, it is hard to say what process opens when you doubleclick the file - there are several possibilities that can be used to handle .js files, like NodeJS or Rhino, etc. Neither of those are installed by default on Ubuntu, though.

Comment: it may come from Wine as muru suggested, but I used this `while true;do ps -o pid,cmd -A |egrep "wine|js";done` and nothing showed up, strange?