# Remove option from "open with..." menu item?

Tags: mime-type, context-menu

I'm using 13.10. I want to remove LibreOffice Writer from my "open with..." menu for html, xml and tex documents, because I almost never use writer (except when someone sends my a word document) and I certainly never use it for html, xml or tex. I have found the following related posts:

1. [How can I remove / change the “Open With” list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115591/how-can-i-remove-change-the-open-with-list)
2. [How to change “Open With” with force and fury? [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197778/how-to-change-open-with-with-force-and-fury)
3. [Remove Wine's Notepad from “Open With” options](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186494/remove-wines-notepad-from-open-with-options)

(1) Suggests:

> Enter the contextual menu of the file and go to the Properties of it. Then, go to Open with tab, right click on the application you want to remove and click on Forget association.

However there is no "Forget association option" in properties > Open With

(2) In re this solution here is the MimeTypes from `/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop`:

```
MimeType=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master;
application/vnd.sun.xml.writer;application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.template;
application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.global;application/msword;application/vnd.ms-word;
application/x-doc;application/x-hwp;application/rtf;text/rtf;
application/vnd.wordperfect;application/wordperfect;
application/vnd.lotus-wordpro;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;
application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template;
application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroenabled.12;
application/vnd.ms-works;application/vnd.stardivision.writer-global;
application/x-extension-txt;application/x-t602;
```

(line breaks added for legibility). I do not know whether "I had to manually change all mentions of userapp-xnview.sh-C2F5D4.desktop to XnView.desktop" in (2) means change in .desktop files (i.e. in my case change contents libreoffice-writer.desktop) or change the name of of the desktop file userapp-xnview.sh-C2F5D4.desktop to XnView.desktop. But, there are no mentions of userapp-xnview.sh-C2F5D4.desktop in libreoffice-writer.desktop nor do I have any userapp-xnview.sh-C2F5D4.desktop in `~/.local/share/applications/mimapps.list` or `/usr/share/applications`.

I have not `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` (should I create one? In which case, what should be its contents; defaults work fine) and here is contents of `~/.local/share/applications/mimapps.list`:

```
[Added Associations]
application/xml=komodo-edit.desktop;
text/html=komodo-edit.desktop;

[Default Applications]
application/xml=komodo-edit.desktop
text/html=komodo-edit.desktop
```

which makes no reference to Writer. I have no `/.local/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop` file.

(3) Consult response to (2).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... I installed XnView .61 as per these instructions
[Install Latest XnView 0.61 in Ubuntu and Linux Mint](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/install-latest-xnview-0-61-in-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/), rebooted, and voila.